# Create a directed graph where the in (or out) degree distribution is scale free

Tags: python, graph, network-programming, networkx

I want to create a directed graph where only the in (or out) degree distribution is scale-free.
Most preferably I want to implement it in python (networkx). I have not found any implementation in networkx.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Say the in-degree distribution is scale-free, what about the out-degree? Could you add more details?

Comment: This is my project wat I have to do: Study epidemics numerically in the SIS model on computer generateddirected networks.  What is the difference between spreading on Erd ̋os-R ́enyi,  and  on  scale-free  networks?   In  case  of  scale-free  networks,examine whether it makes a difference if only the in- (or out-) degreedistribution is scale-free?

Comment: I think you need to be much more specific in your question. Adding this, and perhaps some more details would make it more likely you get some help

Comment: I guess, what I have to do, is create a directed graph, which I create with a configuration model, where I pick in and out connections from two different distributions. One (in or our) from a power-law distribution and the other from a different then a power law distribution... But as I said, my problem is that I dont really know how to do that, if I would know how to do this I would have done already the implementation.

Comment: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.generators.degree_seq.directed_configuration_model.html

This can be a candidate, but now sure

Answer (score 0):

So the solution is with networkX. The key is this configuration model, where you can assign degree lists separately for in and out degrees. So I assigned a power law degree seq for in_degree and I perturbed it to make the distribution not power law... and voila... :D

```py
import networkx as nx
import ndlib.models.ModelConfig as mc
import ndlib.models.epidemics as ep
from ndlib.viz.mpl.DiffusionTrend import DiffusionTrend
from ndlib.viz.bokeh.MultiPlot import MultiPlot
from ndlib.viz.bokeh.DiffusionPrevalence import DiffusionPrevalence
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show
from pprint import pprint
import json, re, demjson
import sys
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



def plot_degree_dist(G):
    in_degrees = G.in_degree()
    in_degrees=dict(in_degrees)
    in_values = sorted(set(in_degrees.values()))
    in_hist = [list(in_degrees.values()).count(x) for x in in_values]

    plt.subplot(2,1,1) 
    plt.grid(False)
    plt.loglog(in_values, in_hist, 'r.') 
    plt.xlabel('k')
    plt.ylabel('p(k)')
    plt.title('In Degree Distribution')

    out_degrees = G.out_degree()
    out_degrees=dict(out_degrees)
    out_values = sorted(set(out_degrees.values()))
    out_hist = [list(out_degrees.values()).count(x) for x in out_values]

    plt.subplot(2,1,2)
    plt.grid(False)
    plt.loglog(out_values, out_hist, 'r.') 
    plt.xlabel('k')
    plt.ylabel('p(k)')
    plt.title('Out Degree Distribution')
    plt.show()


while True:  
    s=[]
    while len(s)<2500:
        nextval = int(nx.utils.powerlaw_sequence(1, 2.5)[0]) #100 nodes, power-law exponent 2.5

        if nextval!=0:
            s.append(nextval)

    if sum(s)%2 == 0:
        break

din = s

z = [0]*len(s)
for k in range(len(s)):

    randnum = int(random.uniform(0,1)*30)

    if random.uniform(0,1)>0.1:
        z[k]=s[k]+randnum
        z[len(s)-k-1]=s[len(s)-k-1]-randnum

    else:
        z[k] = s[k]
        z[len(s)-k-1] = s[len(s)-k-1]

    if k==int(len(s)/2.0-1):
        break

print(sum(s),sum(z))

dout = z


G = nx.directed_configuration_model(din,dout)
G=nx.DiGraph(G) # remove parallel edges
G.remove_edges_from(G.selfloop_edges())
plot_degree_dist(G)
```